# Connecting Chess Engine with a Java program

Tags: engines, software, stockfish

I wanted to make a 1 player chess game.

The idea is:

- The move made by the player would be displayed on the GUI.
- It is sent to the Chess Engine in its own specific understood form.
- Then the result of the Chess engine would be taken and then made visible on the GUI.

Currently I have made no progress on it and am on a dead end. My current program on Java lets 2 players play with each other. The program manages the rules that have to be followed and which moves are illegal. But for a single player game I wanted an AI for my game that can take inputs and give outputs. I searched online for various open source chess engines like Stockfish. But found nothing about using it in my program.

I tried to work on to create my own engine but it was quite a challenge for me. Hence connecting it with an external AI is the only solution I think there is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's break it down:

- You have a working Java chess board that you can use to move pieces
- You want a chess engine (**engine** is a more precise term than **AI**)
- You want to download Stockfish and use it
- You want to invent a new protocol or technology to communicate your chess board with the Stockfish engine

To me, your question is really:

- How to connect an external chess engine such as Stockfish within my own chess GUI in Java?

Useful old posts in this site:

- [Chess Engine API](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/9632/chess-engine-api/9633#9633)
- [What is the optimal way to use Stockfish programmatically?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/15704/what-is-the-optimal-way-to-use-stockfish-programmatically/15707#15707)

Basically, what you need to do is:

1. You shouldn't invent your own technology, you should study the UCI protocol. http://wbec-ridderkerk.nl/html/UCIProtocol.html is a useful reference. I can get you started, do this:

   1. Download Stockfish
   2. Open Stockfish in a console/terminal, don't double-click on it with your mouse
   3. Type `ucinewgame` and then `go movetime 1000`. Do you see Stockfish's move?
   4. Read the protocol specification and learn how to analyze a position, and the output format.
2. Write a UCI output parser. Parse whatever information you want.
3. Use the information to make a move on your chess board.

The only technical difficulty I can see here is to establish a "connection" between your GUI with the engine. This is done by creating a new process, running the engine.

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006035/how-to-create-a-process-in-java has information on how to do it.

Once you have the new process, you can establish a simple standard input/output pipeline. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27081918/java-how-to-send-a-value-to-child-process-using-outputstream has the details. Ask on Stackoverflow if you're not sure.

Comment: I will start working on it immediately and would definitely come back if I hit any roadblocks.

Comment: @Shadow_Sphynx Please start a new question if you have anything new to ask. Consider to accept this answer.

Comment: wow what a great answer!